# How to stream videos from multiple IP cameras using Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, video-processing

```
url='http://192.168.0.103:8080/shot.jpg'
url2='http://192.168.0.102:8080/shot.jpg'
url3='http://192.168.0.3:8080/shot.jpg'

while True:
 imgResp=urllib.urlopen(url)
 imgNp=np.array(bytearray(imgResp.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
 img=cv2.imdecode(imgNp,-1)

 imgResp2=urllib.urlopen(url2)
 imgNp2=np.array(bytearray(imgResp2.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
 img2=cv2.imdecode(imgNp2,-1)

 imgResp3=urllib.urlopen(url3)
 imgNp3=np.array(bytearray(imgResp3.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
 img3=cv2.imdecode(imgNp3,-1)

 cv2.imshow('IPWebcam',img)
 cv2.imshow('IPWebcam2',img2)
 cv2.imshow('IPWebcam3',img3)
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

this is the code i am running.but the result is lagging. i want a faster way to read multiple video streams at a time.

Comment: Does your URL gets refreshed so often to have a new image , or it's always a static image ?

Comment: I'm able to get a good video output without any lags whenever I connect only a single IP cam. But whenever I connect multiple cams, the resulting video lags.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it using a thread with all cams running in a separate thread

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
def ShowCam(url,CameraNumber =1):
    imgResp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imgResp.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(imgNp, -1)
    camName = 'IPWebcam' + str(CameraNumber)
    return camName,img
result = True


from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# do some other stuff in the main process

while result:
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=3)
    async_result1 = pool.apply_async(ShowCam, (url, 1))  # tuple of args for     foo
    rval1 = async_result1.get()
    cv2.imshow(rval1[0],rval1[1])
    async_result2 = pool.apply_async(ShowCam, (url2, 2))  # tuple of args for foo
    rval2 = async_result2.get()
    cv2.imshow(rval2[0],rval2[1])
    async_result3 = pool.apply_async(ShowCam, (url3, 3))  # tuple of args for foo
    rval3 = async_result3.get()
    cv2.imshow(rval3[0],rval3[1])
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Note : Code is not tested , please ignore any typos , but this should solve the purpose . Happy coding :)

Comment: **The code works for some time and then the following error occurs.**

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 21, in <module>
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
  File "W:\Tools\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 732, in __init__
    Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)
  File "W:\Tools\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 187, in __init__
    self._result_handler.start()
  File "W:\Tools\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 736, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread